# How to list all the value of one node attributes with Maya python?

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to list all the attributes and their value for one node (from Mash network), but I got an error when the attribute has no value, even if I use try/except loop

```
attributes = cmds.listAttr('MASH_A_Repro')
for attribute in attributes:
    myAttr='MASH_A_Repro.'+attribute
    try :
        print 'Attribute %s Value %s' % (attribute, cmds.getAttr(myAttr) )
    except KeyError:
        print 'erreur'
```

## Error: RuntimeError: file  line 10: Message attributes have no data values. #

In this case, the first attribute is "Message" and has no value. How can I bypass this one ?

Comment: why not checking with a "if myAttr:", try, exceptt should bypass it

Comment: Good point ! A "try - except" is working. No need of KeyError

Comment: maya is returning runtime error each time so most of the time it is not necessary to specify the type of error

Answer (score 0):

You want to work around message attributes -- as the error says they don't have data.

This will do keep you from blowing up:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

for item in cmds.listAttr('polyPlane1'):
try:
    print cmds.getAttr('polyPlane1.' + item)
except RuntimeError:
    pass
```

But you'll still get an annoying error printout. You can do a cheap precheck by limiting your `listAttr` call to writeable attributes:

```
for item in cmds.listAttr('polyPlane1', w=True):
try:
    print item, cmds.getAttr('polyPlane1.' + item)
except RuntimeError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

use flag: hasData=True

list only attributes that have data (all attributes except for message attributes)

```
attrsList = cmds.listAttr(camShape, keyable=True, visible=True, hasData=True)
```